# pthread_cond_signal() release exactly one thread?

Tags: pthreads, posix

Does pthread_cond_signal unblock exactly one thread? If not, what will be the case it releases more than one thread? The specification says as follows:

> The pthread_cond_signal() function shall unblock at least one of the
>   threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable cond (if
>   any threads are blocked on cond).

Answer (score 3):

The pthreads specification allows for "spurious wakeups" in an implementation.  See, for example, the hypothetical implementation of `pthread_cond_signal` and `pthread_cond_wait` [sketched in the specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html) that allows for just this condition.

The possibility of spurious wakeups is why one always associates some predicate with a condition, and checks that predicate upon wakeup.