# crashed when using multiple consumer thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Only one consumer works fine, but multiple consumers will crash, I am wondering why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;


pthread_mutex_t g_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t g_qs_notempty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t g_qs_notfull = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

queue<string> qs;

void *
producer(void *arg)
{
    static vector<string> vs{"a ","b ","c ","d ","e "};
    static int idx = 0;
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex);
        if(qs.size()==5)//full
            pthread_cond_wait(&g_qs_notfull,&g_mutex);

        qs.push(vs[idx]);
        idx = (idx+1)%5;

        pthread_cond_signal(&g_qs_notempty);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *
consumer(void *arg)
{
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex);
        if(qs.empty())
            pthread_cond_wait(&g_qs_notempty,&g_mutex);
        cout<<qs.front();
        qs.pop();
        pthread_cond_signal(&g_qs_notfull);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main()
{

    struct thread_info *tinfo;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t thread_id;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, &producer, 0);

    pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, &consumer, 0);
    pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, &consumer, 0); //adding this line will crash

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Switch your `if` for a `while`. The thread may be waken up when the queue is empty. "The pthread_cond_signal() call unblocks at least one of the threads that are blocked", I guess it is waking up more than one.

Comment: Also, read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391146/pthread-cond-signal-release-exactly-one-thread , that why you always use while, so you check the condition on wakeup also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is not guaranteed that `_signal()` wakes up only a single thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391146/pthread-cond-signal-release-exactly-one-thread)

So you must recheck your condition upon wakeup. A simply way to fix your code is to switch the `if` for `while`.

Comment: Thanks. In the "Programming with posix thread", it also metioned: "always wait condition variable in loop"